# Rails Creating third table from 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

How can I merge column from one table into another table and save it as a variable, what would be the most efficient way of accomplishing this.  Here is an example:

Table 1:

```
ID  First Name  LastName    contact_id
```

Table 2:

```
Id  Phone   Address email
```

Id from table 2 is a foreign key of contact_id

I need my third table to look like this:

```
Id  Phone   Address Email   person_id
```

person_id corresponds to ID from table 1.

What would be the most efficient way using rails commands to accomplish this result so that it gives me the third table?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add person_id to table 2...

```
Table1Model.all.each do |model|
  x=Table2Model.find(model.contact_id) 
  x.person_id = model.id
  x.save
end
```

Comment: I can't seem to wrap my head around what you are doing here.  Could you please explain it?  I need to get back the result of a third table into a variable so that I may perform other functions with that data.

Comment: Can you please tell me the names of your models so I can help you. It might make my explanation clearer.

Comment: Module Trip has a field called expense_id which corresponds to id from module Expense.  I need a third table that has all the columns from expense including id from Trip.  I plan to do some sort and search function on that third table so I would like to return it as a variable @table_three so that I may perform those functions.